# how to reduce the time of showing blue circle and point in MKMapView

Tags: ios, location, mkmapview

I use a MKMapView to show my current location , I found that when i am doing nothing ,it will take me about 15+ seconds to see the blue circle and point in the map view ,but if i move the map after the map view is start to  locating ,the blue circle and point will show immediately (will dont need 5 seconds now) ,what 's the diffrence between them ? can I short the time to show blue circle in coding ? thanks alot

i create the map

```
self.runMapView = [[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds] autorelease];
        self.runMapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        self.runMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        runMapView.delegate = self;
```

and then :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView_ didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if (loc2 == nil)//loc 2 is the ivar i used to track my first location
    {
        if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(userLocation.location.coordinate))
        {
            self.loc2 = userLocation.location;

            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.location.coordinate, 2000, 2000);
            [runMapView setRegion:region];
        }
    }

}
```

and i add some polylineview to the map,and when i add the mapview to the view ctrl 's view at start ,the mapview 's alpha is set to 0(because i have a button to decide show or hide mapview),i dont know if the map update location in back can cause this problem?

Comment: i see the blue point in my app in the first second, the circle showing the horicontal accuracy may come later.

Comment: can you show some of your code. It's possible you're doing something after the map is moved or the page is loaded to show the user location. In general developers can't do anything to speed up the process, once the map is old it needs to show the user's location it's down to iOS to get it for you and you can't change that. What you can do is change when you app asks for the location and maybe you are doing it too late, but we can't see without some of your code.

Comment: OK,i have post the related code ,please have a look

Comment: OK ,i seemly got some clue of this question now, at first ,the problem of time to locating is caused by i set the mapview 's alpha = 0 after mapview created , and the solution to this is when you reopen the mapview ,reset the mapview's region (the region must be different with the current region of mapview ) this will cause the locating restart.

Answer (score 0):

Create one variable for location manager,
You need to update location just below the mapview initialize like this:

```
self.runMapView = [[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds] autorelease];
    self.runMapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.runMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.runMapView.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```